# How to insert data from two table in one jsp in spring mvc an

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Im using Spring mvc and try insert data from two tables in one jsp

my tables:

```
1.Cars
  Id
  Name
  CityId(FK) 

2.City
  Id
  Name
```

I have tried below but it only select in list, and I wish it is input text to insert data

my bean:

class Cars:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CARS")
public class Car {
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="CITY_ID")
  private City city;      
  // get and set
}
```

class City

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY")
public class City {
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

  private int id;
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  // get and set
}
```

class controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateCar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setCreateCarPage(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                     HttpServletResponse response,
                                     ModelMap model, @RequestParam("citySelected") Integer citySelected,@ModelAttribute("createCar") Car createCar)    {
  City myCity = cityService.getCityById(citySelected);
  createCar.setCityId(myCity);

  carService.createCar(createCar);
  return new ModelAndView("createCar");
 }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="createCar" method="POST" commandName="createCar" action="/CreateCar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset style="width:300px">

    <label>Name of Car</label>
        <form:input path="name" id="name"/>

    <label>Name of City</label>
        <select name="citySelected">
            <c:forEach items="${cityList}" var="city">
                <option value="${city.id}">${city.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Create" style="width:100px;" />
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

How can I create/insert data for name of Cars and City ?

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes in your code.

First in your Controller, you have one method called setCityId() but the argument its a City. Also you dont need the request/response here.

In your request name use capitalization in place of *CreateCar*, use ***createCar***

You should change to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createCar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setCreateCarPage(@ModelAttribute("createCar") Car createCar)    {
  carService.createCar(createCar);
  return new ModelAndView("createCar");
 }
```

The in your JSP code you need to set the city.id of your dropdown to the car

```
<form:form modelAttribute="createCar" method="POST" commandName="createCar" action="/createCar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset style="width:300px">

    <label>Name of Car</label>
        <form:input path="name" id="name"/>

    <label>Name of City</label>
        <select name="citySelected" path="city.id">
            <c:forEach items="${cityList}" var="city">
                <option value="${city.id}">${city.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Create" style="width:100px;" />
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i understand your problem you are using **name** column for both the table you can handle this by adding prefix as table name for eg:

> for car name :  name="Car.name"
>
> for city name : name="Car.City.name"

by placing this your problem will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

IN your jsp  update your select like this  :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="createCar" method="POST" commandName="createCar" action="/CreateCar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset style="width:300px">

    <label>Noi dung</label>
        <form:input path="name" id="name"/>   
    <label>Tinh/Thanh pho</label>
      <form:select path="city">
        <form:options items="${cityList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
    </form:select>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Create" style="width:100px;" />
     </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

and in your controller update this methode :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateCar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setCreateCarPage(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                     HttpServletResponse response,
                                     ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("createCar") Car createCar)    {
   LOG.info("current city "+createCar.getCity().toString());
carService.createCar(createCar);
  return new ModelAndView("createCar");
 }
```